# how to change mouse cursor and sensitivity/acceleration on login screen?

Tags: xfce, manjaro, theme, cursor

I downloaded a cursor theme and put it into `~/.icons` so I could go into Mouse settings and change it.

How do I:

- apply this cursor theme to the login screen
- change the mouse acceleration

on Manjaro running Xfce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the mouse theme in `Settings -> Mouse and Touchpad -> Theme`

Mouse acceleration can be adjusted in the terminal `xinput --set-prop <device id> 'libinput Accel Speed' <acceleration factor>`

You can find the device id of your mouse (assuming it is USB) with `lsusb`